# django queryset manipulation

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I have a queryset within a view and want to manipulate/edit before returning it to the template.

But if I want to convert a queryset to values (below) - so that I can manipulate it - I can't then pass it onto the template. Do I have to convert it back to a queryset? How would I do that?

```
x = RandomModel.objects.values_list()
```

doesn't work, but

```
x = RandomModel.objects.all()
```

does.

I'm manipulating it first, with (e.g.):

```
x[3][4]="test"
```

But even without the manipulation, I can't access it from the template.

I'm passing it to the template with:

```
return render_to_response('index.html', {
    'design_list': x,    
})
```

In the template, I'm trying to access the data with (e.g.):

```
{% for item in design_list %}
    {{ item.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How are you passing it to the template?

Comment: How are you trying to "manipulate" it?

Comment: And what are you trying to do with it in the template?

Comment: +1 for all comments above. Try to answer those questions, especially the template usage, or generalize the part looks causing issue and blocking your further research :)

Comment: I've edited the main submission to include those.

Comment: I'm almost sure, that you are iterating list of tuples in the template, neglecting indexing of tuple items: `{{ item }}` instead of  `{{ item.0 }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as I said in a comment before, you neglect tuple's index. Try next:

```
{% for item in design_list %}
    {{ item.1 }} {# item is a tuple, not a dict #}
{% endfor %}
```

Note the index I use in line {{ item.**1** }}, it returns second element of a tuple (first is usually `id`). So if `x = [(1,'title1'), (2,'title2'), ...]`, you will see `title1` and `title2` on a template.